# How can I crop a bitmap for ImageView?

Tags: java, android, imageview, crop

I know this should be simple , but `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` doesn't crop Image

I got image *1950 pixels* wide and need it to be cropped by parent's width. But `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` doesn't crop Image. What do I need to do in layout to show only first *400 pixels*, for instance or whatever screen/parent width is

Sorry for simple question - tried to Google it - only complicated questions there. And I'm new, so don't downvote please)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rl1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background_color">

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ver_bottompanelprayer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="227px"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:scaleType="matrix"

            android:background="@drawable/ver_bottom_panel_tiled_long" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

if there's only way is to programmaticaly crop it - please give me an advice with a method

Comment: Can you do this like that:first `Bitmap bmp= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ver_bottom_panel_tiled_long);` then  `bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, width, height);` <- paste here the desired width and height. Then `ImageView iv = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.ver_bottompanelprayer);
if (iv != null) {
    iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
}` programmatically.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Alright, I will paste the comment as answer :) ->

```
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl1);

final Options bitmapOptions=new Options();
DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
bitmapOptions.inDensity = metrics.densityDpi;
bitmapOptions.inTargetDensity=1;

/*`final` modifier might be necessary for the Bitmap*/
Bitmap bmp= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ver_bottom_panel_tiled_long, bitmapOptions);
bmp.setDensity(Bitmap.DENSITY_NONE);
bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, rl.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight());
```

Then in the code:

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.ver_bottompanelprayer);
if (iv != null){
  iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
}
```

Cheers :)

Comment: well , great, now I need width parameter be equal to parent's width and height be the image height because I want to crop only image's width

Comment: aaaaand width is a width of parent ?:)

Comment: aaaaand I put this too :)

Comment: so... Isn't there a way to just get parent's width in general? I need to crop ~15 images, wanted to make a method which would work with all

Comment: Well, you jcan just replace the second argument of the function `decodeResource` with the `int` value of the id of the `drawable` (in this case the images).

Comment: well, for example this image is on LinearLayout and it's 400 pixels now. Or it's on a RelativeLayout and it's 800 pixels width. isn't there just a way to find out width of a parent?

Comment: The image from the example is in an `ImageView` (this is the "image" as you see it on the screen), which is a child of a `RelativeLayout` (this is the parent). You should know what's the parent layout, since you're working with concrete dimensions.

Comment: Well, I can work with them manually, but they are not conctere. It's parent's width and image's height.

Comment: You can do this instead: Work with them manually (for the width part) **if** this is not exceeding a threshhold, for example if they're not bigger than the screen size (if(true) - then use the screen size). You can limit the cropped width to several different dimensions like that, even paste some hard coded dimensions if needed in the last `else` for example.

Comment: well, rl width and height=0, but that's not the worst issue - bm's height is 170 although it is 227 pixels high.  I try to avoid this issue in many ways, but Android is downscaling this image in some cases. For example, if I use it as a source to ImageView - it is 227 pixels. But if i put this into bitmap.xml -it's gonna be 170 pixels for no reason. But I want that to be 227 exactly

Comment: Let me check this one, it seems really strange. It seems to me that the downscaling happens because of the density of the device. I'll update the answer with the correct downscaling in a second.

Comment: It is a really big issue I'm fighting with. If I just put an Image as a source to Imageview - it's fine, it is actual size. But if it is in xml - it's totally distorted. if it's a tiled bitmap in xml-it's size gonna be unpredictable. In my case, on my device it's 170 pix height. But I want this to be exactly 227 pix, no less

Comment: That's the "The pixel density to use for the bitmap.", this is used to be compatible with whatever the denisty.

Comment: bitmapOptions.inDensity=sampleSize; - eclipse doesn't know that variable)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35514/discussion-between-g00dy-and-user2234594)

Comment: so how do i know that density?

Comment: With `DisplayMetrics sampleSize = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();` :-)

Comment: Hello @g00dy, I make some changes to `sampleSize` according to the discussion in the comment. Please take a look see if the are appropriate. `DisplayMetrics matrix = getResources().getDisplayMetrics()` and `bitmapOptions.inDensity = matrix.densityDpi`.

Answer (score 10):

You can also crop image by programmatically using [createBitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29).

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, 400, 400);
your_imageview.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

Here 400 is your width & height you can change as per your requirement.

Comment: Well I guess that's called blind team/mate support, I can not describe it better.

Answer (score 1):

Make it `android:scaleType="fitStart"` and for `android:layout_height="400px"`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this programmatically (this ensures you get the right height/width):

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) findVieById(R.id.ver_bottompanelprayer);
DisplayMetrics dm = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(1950, dm.heightPixels);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
image.setLayoutParams(params);
image.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
```