# Android: Crop Bitmap from Bitmap and set as ImageView src

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I'm trying to crop a sprite from a spritesheet, however the cropped image is not the part of the image I specified.

The spritesheet contains sprites with a size of 32 x 32 px and therefore the first sprite should be at pixels 0 to 32 (horizontally) and 0 to 32 (vertically), supposed the most upper left pixel is [0, 0].

```
Bitmap spritesheet = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.spritesheet_32x32);
Bitmap sprite = Bitmap.createBitmap(spritesheet, 0, 0, 32, 32);
```

The ImageView is just a plain ImageView without a src, width or height set.

```
ImageView view = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.player1);
view.setImageBitmap(sprite);
```

But the displayed image is just a much smaller part of the first sprite.
What do I oversee? Is `view.setImageBitmap(sprite);` the right method for this? Does the ImageView need a fix width and height before setting the bitmap?

**EDIT:** Maybe I should get clearer about my layout. There are two ImageViews arranged on a LinearLayout. Here's the XML:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:baselineAligned="false">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleX="-1"
        android:id="@+id/player1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/player2"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18232034/how-can-i-crop-a-bitmap-for-imageview

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;

public class ImageResizer {

public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(String filename,
    int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
// First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
final BitmapFactory.Options
        options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filename, options);
// Calculate inSampleSize
options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);
// Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filename, options);
}

public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
    int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
// BEGIN_INCLUDE (calculate_sample_size)
// Raw height and width of image
final int height = options.outHeight;
final int width = options.outWidth;
int inSampleSize = 1;

if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

    final int halfHeight = height / 2;
    final int halfWidth = width / 2;

    // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
    // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
    while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
            && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
        inSampleSize *= 2;
    }

    // This offers some additional logic in case the image has a strange
    // aspect ratio. For example, a panorama may have a much larger
    // width than height. In these cases the total pixels might still
    // end up being too large to fit comfortably in memory, so we should
    // be more aggressive with sample down the image (=larger inSampleSize).

    long totalPixels = width * height / inSampleSize;

    // Anything more than 2x the requested pixels we'll sample down further
    final long totalReqPixelsCap = reqWidth * reqHeight * 2;

    while (totalPixels > totalReqPixelsCap) {
        inSampleSize *= 2;
        totalPixels /= 2;
    }
}
return inSampleSize;
// END_INCLUDE (calculate_sample_size)
 }

}
```

Call the method

```
Bitmap bmp = ImageResizer.decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(new  File(filePath).getAbsolutePath(), 512, 342);
```

I haven't tried but the follows might work pass the method parameter like
           **imageView.getWidth() , imageView.getHeight()**

Comment: Do I have to set the ImageView's height and width with this method? Right now I'm just passing the spritesheet's original dimensions and the result looks the same.