# add image in my mobile game

Tags: java, android

hi guys i'm working for my puzzle game and i want to add an image and i don't know how to add because i'm just a beginner sorry if i input most of my code here. 
how do i add an image in my buttons for my sliding puzzle game?

this is my code..

```
private void makeMove(final Button b) {
    bad_move = true;
    int b_pos , zuk_pos, b1;
    b1 = Integer.parseInt((String) b.getText());
    b_pos=find_pos(b1);
    zuk_pos=find_pos(0);
    switch(zuk_pos){
    case (0):
        if(b_pos == 1|| b_pos == 3)
            bad_move=false;
    break;
    case(1):
        if(b_pos == 0 || b_pos == 2|| b_pos == 4)
            bad_move=false;
    break;
    case(2):
        if(b_pos == 1 || b_pos == 5)
            bad_move=false;
        break;
    case(3):
        if(b_pos == 0 || b_pos == 4 || b_pos == 6)
        bad_move=false;
    break;
    case(4):
        if(b_pos==1||b_pos==3||b_pos==5||b_pos==7)
        bad_move=false;
        break;
    case(5):
        if(b_pos==2||b_pos==4||b_pos==8)
        bad_move=false;
        break;
    case(6):
        if(b_pos==3||b_pos==7)
        bad_move=false;
        break;
    case(7):
        if(b_pos==4||b_pos==6||b_pos==8)
        bad_move=false;
        break;
    case(8):
        if(b_pos==5||b_pos==7)
        bad_move=false;
        break;  
    }
    if(bad_move == true){
        // to be decide
        return;
    }
    cells.remove(b_pos);
    cells.add(b_pos, 0);
    cells.remove(zuk_pos);
    cells.add(zuk_pos, b1);

    fill_grid();
    for(int i = 0;i<9; i++){
        if(cells.get(i) != goal[i]){
            return;
        }
    }
    //to be done for finishing touches 
}
private void fill_grid() {
    for(int i =0; i<9;i++){
        int text = cells.get(i);
AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams absParams = 
    (AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams) buttons[text].getLayoutParams();

switch(i){
case(0):
    absParams.x = 5;
absParams.y = 5;
buttons[text].setLayoutParams(absParams);
break;
case(1):

    absParams.x = 110;
    absParams.y = 5;
    buttons[text].setLayoutParams(absParams);
    break;
case(2):

    absParams.x = 215;
    absParams.y = 5;
    buttons[text].setLayoutParams(absParams);
    break;
case(3):

    absParams.x = 5;
    absParams.y = 110;
    buttons[text].setLayoutParams(absParams);
    break;
case(4):

    absParams.x =110;
    absParams.y =110;
    buttons[text].setLayoutParams(absParams);
    break;
case(5):

    absParams.x = 215;
    absParams.y =110;
    buttons[text].setLayoutParams(absParams);
    break;
case(6):

    absParams.x = 5;
    absParams.y = 215;
    buttons[text].setLayoutParams(absParams);
    break;
case(7):

    absParams.x = 110;
    absParams.y = 215;
    buttons[text].setLayoutParams(absParams);
    break;
case(8):

    absParams.x = 215;
    absParams.y = 215;
    buttons[text].setLayoutParams(absParams);
    break;

        }
    }   
}
public int find_pos(int element){
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0;i<9; i++){
        if(cells.get(i) == element){
            break;
        }
    }
    return i;

}

private Button[] findButtons() {
    Button[] b = new Button[9];

    b[0] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button00);
    b[1] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
    b[2] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button02);
    b[3] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button03);
    b[4] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button04);
    b[5] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button05);
    b[6] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button06);
    b[7] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button07);
    b[8] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button08);
    return b;
}
```

Comment: Well, you can simply use ImageButtons, or set the background of the regular buttons. What seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

first place whatever image you are wanting to use into your drawable folder which you can find in your res folder.

You need to go into the .XML file of what you are referencing with this code in the layout folder and use the background to reference the image like this.

```
          <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:background="@drawable/your_image" >
```

now your image should be on your button. you can mess with these values and add more to get it how you want. It should be fairly straight forward.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. but i will have to crop it one by one to able to finish it.. i want a code that make my image to automatically cropped using a java code and it will be added using also a java code.

Comment: @JhayPat Ah I see what you want now. you should be able to use an imageView like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18232034/how-can-i-crop-a-bitmap-for-imageview) and programmatically calculate the bounds of each and just make the imageViews clickable, so it acts like a button.