# How to resize image in Android without shrinking it?

Tags: android, image-processing

I know this is a bit unusual, but I want to resize the bounds of an image without the image itself being scaled down.

For example, when I have an 200x200 image, and resize it to 100x200 the result should just be half of the image, where the other half is just cut.

Is that possible?

Comment: this might be it http://stackoverflow.com/a/6333518/781729

Comment: I think you are confused with a CANVAS size of 100x200 where you place in an Image of 200x200 so it doesnt scale the image. It appeares Croped  -- http://pc.net/helpcenter/answers/canvas_size_vs_image_size

Comment: @Tasos But what I need is to cut one part off while it's still in memory, not putting it into a canvas where it "overflows" and isn't displayed completely.

Comment: Tahe a look here on how to CROP an image by code -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18232034/how-can-i-crop-a-bitmap-for-imageview

Comment: @Tasos Thanks, that did the job ^^

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you resize the image in your app, but if you resize any 200x200 image to 100x200, this result will be a part of your initial image, depending on the starting point.(could be the 1st half starting at pixel 0, the 2nd half starting at pixel 100 or any other half in between depending on the starting pixel)

Comment: That's what I want, but the question is HOW