# Where to call Crop Image Before Setting to ImageView

Tags: java, android, image, crop

Where to call Crop Image Before Setting to Image view as I'm not getting it as my Image not getting cropped for this activity. As I want to crop the Image and post the Cropped Image to the server as well

```
@Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());
            for (File temp : f.listFiles()) {
                if (temp.getName().equals("temp.jpg")) {
                    f = temp;
                    break;
                }
            }
            try {
                Bitmap bitmap;
                BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath(),
                        bitmapOptions);
                imgNavHeaderPic.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                String path = android.os.Environment
                        .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + File.separator
                        + "Phoenix" + File.separator + "default";
                f.delete();
                OutputStream outFile = null;
                File file = new File(path, String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
                createBitmapAndAssign(Uri.fromFile(file));
                try {
                    outFile = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, outFile);
                    outFile.flush();
                    outFile.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if (requestCode == 2) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            createBitmapAndAssign(data.getData());
            String[] filePath = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePath, null, null, null);
            c.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]);
            String picturePath = c.getString(columnIndex);
            c.close();
            Bitmap thumbnail = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
            imgNavHeaderPic.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
            Drawable bitmap = imgNavHeaderPic.getDrawable();

        }
    }
}
```

As I'm also compressing my Image well...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I crop a bitmap for ImageView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18232034/how-can-i-crop-a-bitmap-for-imageview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one

```
try{
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), 
    R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, 400, 400);
    your_imageview.setImageBitmap(bm);
}catch(Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();     
}
```

Comment: where should i try this...means where in the code, I'm not getting it pls help me

Comment: where you have to send the image to server?

Comment: if you only need to crop image for imageview you can simply do this with  glide library's override method but if you have to send the image over the network the image have to be in you storage. explain me your scenario.

Comment: i want to crop the image and send to the server also set it to Imageview as that of whatsapp