# Crop image from shape pattern in Android

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I have this shape:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"/>
    </item>
    <item
        android:bottom="0dp"
        android:left="-100dp"
        android:right="-100dp"
        android:top="-80dp">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/darkViolet" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

in my sample app header.I have inserted this shape as a `background` to `RelativeLayout` as a following code:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:background="@drawable/curve_header_bg" />
```

this is results:

[image: header]

I want to user image profile fill this shape exactly like my shape and have shape's curve.I do not have any idea how could i do this.I just know,i have to create custom view but i do not know, how could i crop user image like my shape.
Like this (I have created with **Photoshop**) :
[image]

Comment: haven't you got the image in curve already in the last picture?

Comment: @Umair I have created with Photoshop my last picture.

Comment: take a look at my answer. you can do something like that to achieve what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this in your layout. Get an **imageview** then add it's **background** and give the **`src = "yourImage"`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/tagsVerticalLineup"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="150dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:background="@drawable/test"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
```

you will get something like this and I think that's what you want right ?

[image]

Comment: I will try and i'll announce you

Comment: @sayreskabir yeah sure no problem.

Comment: I do that, but Photo not cropped !!!  https://ibb.co/n7vKhS  look bottom of image

Comment: @sayreskabir it won't crop yes, In order to do that, you need to use paddings, and imageView android:scaleType=" "

Comment: @sayreskabir if you want to crop image before setting it to imageview take a look at this answer, it might help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18232034/how-can-i-crop-a-bitmap-for-imageview

Comment: this is my code and image https://ibb.co/iZt06n  . where is my mistake?

Comment: @sayreskabir your code is alright try giving more height to your parent layout. and also take a look at the answer for how to crop the image.